# Detect browser version with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm serving a static website on S3 through CloudFront. 
It's possible to trigger a lambda function each time CloudFront serves a file (Lambda@Edge).

[This example](https://codingsans.com/blog/lambda-edge-redirect-users-based-on-browser-language) shows how a Lambda@Edge nodejs function can detect a users language settings in the browser and serve files accordingly. Pretty cool!

**Question:**
Is it possible to detect what browser a users is using?

Use case: My website does not support older browsers (IE 11 and below), and I want to redirect to a page explaining this.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the User-agent header in Viewer request and callback response (redirect) for older browsers.

https://www.reliam.com/blog/handling-requests-with-lambda-at-edge/
Use the response example mentioned here for redirection: (Example: Generating an HTTP Redirect (Generated Response))

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-generated-response-examples